# How to remove the word optional when assigning a double as text in a label?

Tags: json, swift

I am getting a series of values from JSON, one of which defined by the `totalBuy` this value is defined as bool

```
struct PurchaseTotals: Codable {

    var totalBuy: Double?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case sumTotal = "totalBuy"
    }
}
```

When I try to assign this double as text for a label the word optional shows up in the front:

I am assigning the value like this:

```
    sumLabel.text = "\(totalBuy)"
```

How can the word optional be removed?

In addition to this is it possible to format the value within the label to contain a comma when necessary, the value of `totalBuy` is a number that can sometimes look like `"1000"` where a comma is necessary after the one `(1,000).` ?

Comment: The question here is if totalBuy should really be an optional. You should declare it as a constant and non optional. Btw your code as it is wouldn't compile. The CodingKeys enumeration is pointless `struct PurchaseTotals: Codable { let totalBuy: Double }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in `Codable` `case` names in `enum CodingKeys` must exactly match the `property` in your `Codable` type.

So, it should look like,

```
struct PurchaseTotals: Codable {
    var sumTotal: Double?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sumTotal = "totalBuy"
    }
}
```

In the above code, `sumTotal` is the property name and `totalBuy` is the key that you must get from API. If it is the other way round, you can change the code accordingly.

**Problem-1** 
Now, since `sumTotal` is an `optional`, that's why you're getting optional printed in your `label`.

You need to *unwrap* the `sumTotal` before using it.

**Problem-2**
Now, since you need to format the `sumTotal` before using it, you can create a variable in `PurchaseTotals` itself that will return the `formattedSumTotal` String.

So, the combined code goes like,

```
struct PurchaseTotals: Codable {
    var sumTotal: Double?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sumTotal = "totalBuy"
    }

    lazy var formattedSumTotal: String? =  {
        if let sumTotal = sumTotal {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            let str = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: sumTotal))
            return str
        }
        return nil
    }()
}
```

Use the `formattedSumTotal` like,

```
label.text = purchaseTotals.formattedSumTotal
```

Comment: When I assign formattedSumTotal to the label I get the error: `Instance member 'formattedSumTotal' cannot be used on type 'purchaseTotals'`

Comment: `purchaseTotals` is the object of PurchaseTotals type. In your code see what is the name of your object and use formattedSumTotal on that object.

Comment: Correct, the objects name is written right after the word "struct" right?

Comment: No. That’s the type you’ve created. You must have created the object of that type right?

Comment: Where do you define `purchaseTotals` in your example?

Comment: In the code you added, how are you getting the totalSum when setting it into label? You must be accessing any object right?

Comment: Is there a simple way to add a constant symbol in front of the value? For example a "$"

Comment: Simply add the $ where you’re creating the formattedSumTotal, i.e. `let str = “$” + formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: sumTotal))`

Comment: I appreciate your help PGDev,  can you take a look at this related issue I am having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062654/how-to-filter-what-type-of-information-is-shown-in-a-uitableview-swift-json

Answer (score 1):

I think that yuou're looking for [NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)

```
// If I have a value for totalBuy go ahead
if let totalBuy = totalBuy {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    let formattedString = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: totalBuy)) ?? ""
    sumLabel.text = "\(formattedString)"
} else {
    sumLabel.text = ""
}
```