# How to filter what type of information is shown in a UITableView | Swift JSON

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that is getting information from JSON the issue is I would like to only show the `String` values in the `UITableView` excluding any `Doubles`

The structure of the JSON decoder is:

```
struct PurchaseTotals: Codable {
    var sumTotal: Double?
    var animal: String?
    var name: String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sumTotal = "sumTotal"
        case animal = "animal"
        case sumTotal = "name"
    }

    lazy var formattedSumTotal: String? =  {
        if let sumTotal = sumTotal {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            let str = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: sumTotal))
            return str
        }
        return nil
    }()
}
```

And in the `cellForRowAt` I define the structure with the variable `portfolio`:

```
var portfolio: PurchaseTotals
```

And in `cellForRowAt` the cells are being populated and are being shown in the UITableView the following way.

First I define the JSON structure with the variable `structure`:

```
var structure = [PurchaseTotals]()
```

Then I set the variable `portfolio` equal to `structure[indexPath.row]`

```
portfolio = structure[indexPath.row]
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Jake","animal":"dog"},{"name":"Mary","animal":"cat"},{"sumTotal":100}]
```

Meaning the number of cells right now is 3 but I would like 2 cells, excluding the sumTotal.

**UPDATE:**

```
import UIKit


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


    var dataSource  = [PurchaseTotals]()


    var structure = [PurchaseTotals]() {
        didSet {
            dataSource = structure.filter({ $0.sumTotal == nil })
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! ScheduleCell
        var portfolio = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

struct PurchaseTotals: Codable {
    var sumTotal: Double?
    var animal: String?
    var name: String?


lazy var formattedSumTotal: String? =  {
    if let sumTotal = sumTotal {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        let str = "$" + formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: sumTotal))!
        return str
    }
    return nil
}()

}
```

Comment: Do you want to use sumTotal anywhere?

Comment: Yes sumTotal is being used in a UILabel but should not be included in the UITableView

Comment: Added the answer. Check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate variable named `dataSource` that will contain only those elements from `structure` having `sumTotal = nil`, i.e

```
var structure = [PurchaseTotals]() {
    didSet {
        dataSource = structure.filter({ $0.sumTotal == nil })
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
var dataSource  = [PurchaseTotals]()
```

In the above code, the `dataSource` `array` will be updated in `didSet` of `structure` when the `structure` `array` is filled after getting the API response.

So, `structure` will contain the actual data from API response. And `dataSource` will contain the filtered content from `structure`.

Now, use `dataSource` `array` in the `UITableViewDataSource` methods like,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let portfolio = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    //rest of the code...
}
```

---

**Note:** There is no need for `enum CodingKeys` if the *property names* exactly match the *API keys*. So the `struct PurchaseTotals` can be rewritten as,

```
struct PurchaseTotals: Codable {
    var sumTotal: Double?
    var animal: String?
    var name: String?

    lazy var formattedSumTotal: String? =  {
        //rest of the code...
    }()
}
```

**Edit-1:**

Use sample *JSON* instead of *API* response like,

```
let str = """
[{"name":"Jake","animal":"dog"},{"name":"Mary","animal":"cat"},{"sumTotal":100}]
"""
if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([PurchaseTotals].self, from: data)
        print(structure)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Here is the whole code that is working fine for me,

```html
struct PurchaseTotals: Codable {
    var sumTotal: Double?
    var animal: String?
    var name: String?
    
    lazy var formattedsumTotal: String? =  {
        if let sumTotal = sumTotal {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            let str = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: sumTotal))
            return str
        }
        return nil
    }()
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var structure = [PurchaseTotals]() {
        didSet {
            dataSource = structure.filter({ $0.sumTotal == nil })
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    var dataSource  = [PurchaseTotals]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let str = """
        [{"name":"Jake","animal":"dog"},{"name":"Mary","animal":"cat"},{"sumTotal":100}]
        """
        if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([PurchaseTotals].self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: The same issue persists, all three rows are still showing up

Comment: Have you used the same code? Add your UITableViewDataSource methods in the question.

Comment: My apologies for the delay, please have a look at my update, I am using a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController. I have included most of my code so can have a look.

Comment: Is the json response exactly same as in question?

Comment: Yes the json is exactly the same

Comment: Is there anything else I could try, I am really struggling with this problem, I just don’t want that last section (sumTotal) to show up in the TableView

Comment: Can you try with the sample JSON and see if it works instead of using the API response? That way we'll know where the issue lies.

Comment: What do you mean with the sample JSON ? That is exactly what my api looks like, I just changed a few names

Comment: I've added the code for sample JSON. Try that and see what response are you getting. This is just for the debug purpose.

Comment: Ok I have tried the JSON and the third cell row is still showing up

Comment: Add the screenshot of the output.

Comment: I've added the whole code for the problem statement.

Comment: I did get the extra cell for sumTotal to disappear now there is only 2, but remember I still need to assign the value of sumTotal to a textLabel, but now it is not showing up in that textLabel

Comment: That's why we still have `structure`. Get the sumTotal from structure's last element.

Comment: I am doing `label.text = portfolio.formattedSumTotal` where `portfolio: PurchaseTotals `

Comment: Because no every portfolio contains the value of sumTotal. And hence no formattedSumTotal

Comment: Sorry, I am misunderstanding. How can this be fixed?

Comment: `label.text = "\(structure.last?.sumTotal ?? 0.0)"`

Comment: Is there a way to reformat the value with commas where necessary?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Add back the formatting like instead of 1000 do 1,000

Comment: That give me the error `Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'last' is a get-only property`

Comment: I don't even understand what you're trying to do. The error Is because in your code you're changing structure's last object. And in the code I provided there is nothing like that.

Comment: No, I am not changing the structure's last object. I am not sure what to do

Comment: I have, is there perhaps another way to format the text once it is already in the label?

Comment: Formatting the value as money is all that is not working

Comment: Show the code where you're updating the money value in label.

Comment: The way it currently works is without the formattedSumTotal:  `sumLabel.text = "\(structure.last?.sumTotal ?? 0.0)" `

Comment: I'm asking you to add the code. I cannot identify the issue with you adding the required code.

Comment: This works perfectly, I just need to format it as money

Comment: `sumLabel.text = structure.last?.formattedsumTotal`. This isn't working?

Comment: Correct, it is not working. And my code is exactly like yours

Comment: Are there any alternatives?

Comment: That why I want to look into the code where you are getting the error when using formattedsumTotal. And in the code you've added, I cannot find formattedsumTotal anywhere. Please recheck,.

Comment: Please have a look, the variable formattedSumTotal is being created there

Comment: No same issue still occurs

Comment: PGDev do you have a few minutes to go into a chat room with me? I wanted to ask for some advice

Comment: Sure. Send me the link for that.

Comment: I don't think I have a big enough reputation to start one, do you mind starting one?

Comment: Ping me once you enter the room.